# How do I end my program using while in python with the ff code

Tags: python

```
import sys

finish = True
lst = []
while finish:
    num = int(input('How many numbers will be in the list?: '))
    
    for n in range(num):
        numbers = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
        lst.append(numbers)
        
    print('The largest number is: ', max(lst), '\n The smallest number is: ', min(lst))
    
    q = input('Do you wish to exit?: ')
    if 'y' in q.lower:
        print('We are done!')
        break
    else :
        print('We will continue!')
        continue
    
sys.exit(0)
```

Here is my code in python and it keeps on giving an error whenever I answer the question "Do you wish to exit"

"TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable"

That is the error that I always get

The program should end when the user answered 'Yes' and the program will continue if the user answered 'No'

Comment: `lower` is a method. Use `lower()`

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the "q.lower" with "q.lower()" since lower() is a built-in method